# Why is flutter post request to fastapi server returning a "connection timeout " error?

Tags: android, flutter, http-post, fastapi

i am trying to get a sentiment from text entered in my flutter app using a fastapi service.
here is the code for fastapi.its working when i am using the swagger utility .
here is the code snippet of the fastapi server with post request:

```py
@app.post('/predict')
def predict_sentiment(data: SentimentData):
    data = data.dict()
    print(data)
    text = data['text']
    output = predict(vectoriser, LRmodel, text)
    if (output == 1):
        prediction = "positive"
    else:
        prediction = "negative"
    return prediction
```

This is the "SentimentData" in the above code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SentimentData(BaseModel):
    text: str
```

and here is the part of the app that handles the post request:

```
RoundButton(
    title: 'detect sentiment',
    onPress: () async {
        var url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/predict');
        var data = {
            'text': descriptionController.text.toString()
        };
        var body = json.encode(data);
        print(body);
        print("the ends");
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        };

        // Send the POST request
        var response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
        print(response.statusCode);
        // Handle the response
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var result = response.body;
            print(result);
            sentiment = result;
        // Process the result
        } else {
            print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
        }
    }
),
```

This is the "sentiment" variable that is modified in the above code

```
  TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  String sentiment = "";
```

and this is the console output:

> I/ViewRootImpl@14bc534MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0
> I/ViewRootImpl@14bc534MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1
> I/flutter (30724): {"text":"this is a sad post"}
> I/flutter (30724): the ends
> E/flutter (30724): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection timed out
> E/flutter (30724): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:94:7)
> E/flutter (30724): 
> E/flutter (30724): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
> E/flutter (30724): 
> E/flutter (30724): #2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:12)
> E/flutter (30724): 
> E/flutter (30724): #3      _AddPostScreenState.build. (package:project_phase_one/screens/add_post.dart:95:42)
> E/flutter (30724): 
> E/flutter (30724):

i am trying to get the sentiment in the user input text in the "descriptionController",send it to the fast api server and get the sentiment as "negative" or "positive" to the varible "sentiment".